# Change text live in another div when you type in textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm having a problem with my textarea. I have tried a lot of things to make the text in a div change (real-time) when you type in a textarea. 
So for example, you have a textarea, and a completely different div that has nothing to do with the textarea. The point is, if it is possible to make text change real-time, and if so where to start?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What have you tried so far? Post some code which doesn't work, and we'll try to point you in the right direction.

Comment: do you mean to say the text in text area appear in div when typing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the time it took me to write the jsfiddle, it looks like others have beaten me to answers.  Though I think my answer is a little better because it caches the jQuery objects for a faster response which is important with things like live typing.  http://jsfiddle.net/nrVM8/

```
$(function() {
    $source=$("#source");
    $output=$("#output");
    $source.keyup(function() {
       $output.text($source.val());
    });
});
```

Comment: much appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
$("#mytextarea").keyup(function() {
    $("#mydiv").html($("#mytextarea").val());
});
```

Answer (score 2):

HTML:

```
<textarea id="input">
</textarea>
<div id="preview">
```

JS:

```
$("#input").keyup(function() {
    $("#preview").text(this.value);
});
```

See this in action [here](http://jsfiddle.net/)